# Is there any way to name a variable with another variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to name a variable via another variable for a small game. I have made a class for all bullets and a seperate one for enemies.

```
class bruh(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        print(x)
for x in range(1,11):
    x = bruh(x)
```

What I *want* the code to do is to create 10 variables each labbeled 1-10 which each are the bruh() object so they print x when created. Not sure if i'm stupid or not but is there any way to achieve this or something similar?

Comment: The common beginner question "how can I create variables programmatically" is almost always resolved with "don't; use a dictionary variable or a list".

Comment: You probably just want an array/list, not really dynamic variable names (which is possible in python but really hacky and more problematic than just using a list)

Comment: you can use the  `getattr` and/or `setattr` function depending on what type of variable to set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wouldn't be so efficient to create them, instead a list would come in handy:

```
l = []
for x in range(1,11):
    l.append(bruh(x))
```

Or:

```
l = [bruh(x) for x in range(1, 11)]
```